# Android Studio version not change although i have updated it

Tags: android, android-studio, updates

I tried to update my android studio from 1.5.1 to 2.2.2. While i have finished my update and open android studio the versions not changed and still 1.5.1 version. Why this happen and what is the solution. Sorry for my english. Thank you

Comment: Try to set up Environment Variable, The following link may help you, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTrUX1kUpDo

Comment: check if you have 2 android studios installed after update?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're already using Linux as I had on Ubuntu the same problem.
Close Android Studio, remove `android-studio` folder and go to tools.android.com to download 2.2.1 version. The latest 2.2.2 is not available here now, expecting due to problems with Linux systems